# [Android]: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field error_color_material

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I am getting the following error when trying to show an error message on the UI's `TextInputLayout`:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.blablabla.appname, PID: 23691
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field error_color_material of type I in class Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$color; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$color' appears in /data/app/com.blablabla.appname-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk)
        at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(TextInputLayout.java:654)
        at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setError(TextInputLayout.java:721)
        at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setError(TextInputLayout.java:708)
        at com.blablabla.appname.activity.SetupProfileActivity.validateUsername(SetupProfileActivity.java:465)
```

---

**SetupProfileActivity.java:465:**

```
private boolean validateUsername() {
    final String username = inputUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    if (inputUsername.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        inputLayoutUsername.setError(getText(R.string.username_warning)); // Line 465
        requestFocus(inputUsername);
        return false;
    } else {
        inputLayoutFullName.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }

    return true;
}
```

What's the issue? I tried looking up but couldn't find anything related to the `No field error_color_material` message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that my app module's build.Gradle was missing a support library:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Everything was resolved after adding that then resyncing!

Comment: or add this: 
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'